# Distribution through Apple Enterprise : employees only?

Tags: iphone, deployment, enterprise, iphone-developer-program

Take the situation in which I have created a number of apps and would like to distribute it to  people for testing, but without having to know their UUID. Each app would only be distributed to a few people but I don't want to have to ask for their UUID.

Does the enterprise distribution program support this? So that I can archive and distribute the app without specifying UUIDs to people who are **non-employees**?

Comment: Note that another option is the Custom B2B App program, which lets you distribute apps via the App Store, but only to selected users.  It's a little complicated, but it does get around the "only within your organization" issue.

Comment: @JoshuaI am facing the same problem, can you please tell me the correct way that how can i publish my app in around 3000 employees using IOS Enterprise program? Thanks

Comment: @APG As Kristopher mentions, the B2B program may be your best bet, see here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Answer (score 1):

The enterprise distribution program does allow you to distribute apps to select users without knowing their UUID. The iOS Enterprise Distribution guide explains everything you need to know to distribute apps outside of the app store. In short, you can host your app on a web server that requires authentication.

Check out this link for more information http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/